# Escaping user input for YAML file

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I need to write user input to my YAML file. The user input needs to be interpreted as plain text.
What do I need to escape? How to escape it?

To generate the yaml file i use Symfony's Yaml component. For example:

**Code:**

```
$result = ['key' => '@text'];
echo $yaml->dump($result);
```

**Actual output:**

```
key:    '@text'
```

When I load this output with Symfony's yaml service, I get a fatal error:

> Invalid type for path "key". Expected scalar, but got object.

**Desired output:** (because @ is an [reserved indicator](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2774228))

```
key:    '@@text'
```

This output loads OK and is interpreted as `@text`.

Comment: I would hope that Symfony's YAML component would handle escaping itself…

Comment: @Chris me too, but that's not the case :/

Comment: Could you edit your question and add an example of input that doesn't work as expected, along with expected output and actual output?

Comment: I'm not a big YAML user, but isn't your actual output valid since it's in a quoted string? [This linter](http://www.yamllint.com/) seems to think so…

Comment: It might be valid, but doesn't have meaning of plain text. When I try to load such YAMLfile, I get this error: `Invalid type for path "key". Expected scalar, but got object.`

Comment: Well, the linter I linked to earlier says it's valid. [This online parser](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) (based on [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/)) parses it successfully. So does [this one](https://nodeca.github.io/js-yaml/) (based on [JS-YAML](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml)). Maybe the question should be about getting Symfony's YAML component to parse valid YAML?

Comment: The error message indicates that there is a bug in Symfony's YAML parser. `'@test'` is a YAML scalar, but the error message claims it is not. I advice to file a bug report, we won't get anywhere here.

Answer (score 1):

The output is perfectly valid. The dumper does escape the value by putting it in single quotes. It would be invalid without the single quotes.

There is no reason the `@` should be doubled and doubling an `@` is not a syntactic device in YAML. `@@text` would still be an invalid YAML scalar without quotes.

Comment: It might be valid, but doesn't have meaning of plain text. When I try to load such YAMLfile, I get this error: Invalid type for path "key". Expected scalar, but got object.

Comment: `'@text'` is a quoted YAML scalar. It is different from a plain scalar (i.e. one without quotes) because it will always be interpreted as string (`'42'` is always a string while `42` may be interpreted as integer). If you get an error while loading the YAML, you should ask a question about that. It is an information completely missing from your current question.

Comment: I've added that to the question.